# Pandas: Bar plot using sum of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID | A | B | C | ...
--------------------
1  | 0 | 0 | 0 | ...
2  | 1 | 1 | 1 | ...
3  | 1 | 1 | 0 | ...
```

There are many columns and rows, and the values are binary. I want to use barplot (or pieplot) to plot the percentage of the sum of the rows. This is a kind of visualization I am looking for: [image: Bar plot]
I tried using `df.sum(axis=1).reset_index()` to get the sum of each row, but I don't know what's next. Any plotting tool is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you do the sum of rows using:

```
arr = df.sum(axis=1)
```

You can calculate the repetitions of each element in the array using numpy:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
myDictionary = dict(zip(unique, counts))
plt.bar(myDictionary.keys(), myDictionary.values(), width, color='g')
```

And use this dictionary to plot the bar plot.

Other way is just plot the histogram of the `arr`:

```
plt.hist(arr, bins=np.arange(arr.min(), arr.max()+1))
```

This is a general idea to how to proceed going from the sum of each row of the data-frame.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a starting point. The idea is to divide length of df to get `%`

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,1,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [1,0,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,0,1]
],columns = ['a','b','c'])
k = df.sum()/len(df)
k.plot.bar()
```

[image]

```
k = df.sum(axis=1)/len(df.columns)
# or k = df.sum(axis=1)/(len(df.columns)-1) to remove ID column
k.plot.bar()
```

[image]